# how to display image on mouse over by css

Tags: jquery, css

I have few images, which come dynamically from database.

When a user hovers over a image, the name should display below the image.

How can I do this with CSS, or jquery?

Check the image below, this is how it should be.

[image]

My code is

```
<div class="blue_strip_icon" style="padding-right: 15px;">
    <a href="<%= pag.page.id %>" class="icon_link">
    <img src="<%= @icon %>" title="<%= pag.page.page_title %>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS is

```
.blue_strip_icon{
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n66Tf/1/

---

You can use the CSS `:after` psuedo element to create a customized tooltip element.

Check this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n66Tf/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- render the tooltip text from the server itself -->
<a href="http://google.com" tooltip="Hello World">Hello</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;   
}
a:hover:after {
    content: attr(tooltip); /* use the tooltip attribute instead of hardcoding */
    color: blue;
    top: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: you are right but my content will come from database. I cann't hardcoded it in css file :(

Comment: That can be easily done by using an attribute of your link as the text to use for the pseudo tooltip. Check the updated demo in the answer.

Comment: you're welcome. this is one of those techniques i learned from no where else but stackoverflow. :0)

Comment: I have done some changes and it works here http://jsfiddle.net/n66Tf/4/ but in my firefox it is not working correct.

Comment: i see your fiddle is working as expected. can you share a link to your actual implementation so i can see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a plugin like [jQuery tooltip](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) and then display the tooltip as an image

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sibling `~` selector like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Bv/

Comment: i have done some changes and it stop working. please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Bv/4/

Comment: You must have removed `:hover` from `img` on `img:hover ~ .no_nev { display: block; }` - working again: http://jsfiddle.net/Zp2Bv/5/

Answer (score 0):

this tutorial can help you : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-better-tooltip-with-jquery-awesomeness/